# min value of long throws an exception

Tags: java

The method is supposed to reverse a long integer but when I used a min value of long it throws an exception.

```
public long reverse(long number)
//reverses a number
{
    long newNumber = number;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        newNumber *= -1l;
    }
    String numString = Long.toString(newNumber);
    char[] numChars = numString.toCharArray();
    numChars = reverse(numChars);
    numString = String.valueOf(numChars);
    newNumber = Long.parseLong(numString);

    if (number < 0)
    {
        newNumber *= -1l;
    }
    return newNumber;
}
```

Comment: `1)` What exception? `2)` I don't understand the question.

Comment: What was the exact value you input to this method? (the value of `number`) Also, what was the exception?

Comment: It looks like you are calling your method but passing it a `char[]` not a `long` (numChars = reverse(numChars);)

Comment: If you multiple `Long.MIN_VALUE` by minus one, it gives `Long.MIN_VALUE`. So if you reverse the characters, there will be a minus sign at the end.

Comment: Because your code is wrong,  parameters passed to reverse method is incorrect. Therefore, argument illegal exception.

Comment: I have already created the reverse method of chars. Sorry, I'll just show the code later. Also, the if statement above serves as the countermeasure for the negative integer. It already worked on the Max value of long and some negative long integers but not the Long.MIN_VALUE, where it throws a NumberFormatException because of the - in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider - maybe using integers will do what you want:

pseudo code:

```
int rev(const int ptest)
{
   int reversed = 0;
   int sign=(ptest<0)?-1:1
   int k = abs(ptest);

   while (k > 0)
   {
       reversed = base * reversed + k % 10;
       k /= 10;
   }
   return reversed*sign;

}
```

Comment: That's going to be difficult for a Long, especially Long.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: Yup +1 @laune. it needs a change to accommodate negative numbers. Fixed, thanks. But the point I failed to make: integer operations are usually less convoluted and less resource intensive.

Comment: but what does base stand for ?

Comment: The whole point is that also Integer.MIN_VALUE is going to cause a problem. Other values will also fail, see pbabcdefp's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The value Long.MIN_VALUE doesn't have a Long positive "opposite". Multiplying this value by -1 results in Long.MIN_VALUE! This contains a leading '-', and so your reversed sequence of digit characters ends with a '-' and this throws NumberFormatException.

You'll need some special handling for this value, or exclude it.

This is *force majeure* for binary numbers represented in two's complement. A byte ranges from -128 to 127, and (check the MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE constants) the same is true for short, int, long.

The smallest negative value in bits is 100...000. If you multiply this by -1 which is 111...111 you can easily see that the result is 100...000, with all higher order bits being silently (!) discarded.

**Later**

Avoid all problems by using BigInteger:

```
static BigInteger reverse(BigInteger bi)  {
  int sign = bi.signum();
  if( sign < 0 ){
    bi = bi.abs();
  }
  String sbi = bi.toString();
  char[] numChars = sbi.toCharArray();
  numChars = reverse(numChars);
  String numString = String.valueOf(numChars);
  bi = new BigInteger( numString );
  if( sign < 0 ){
    bi = bi.multiply( new BigInteger( "-1" ) );
  }
  return bi;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the easiest way to handle `Long.MIN_VALUE` is to just write the following line right at the top.:`if (number == Long.MIN_VALUE) { return -8085774586302733229L; }`. This is very ugly, but any other way will make your method much more complex.

Comment: On the other hand, loads of other values will throw a `NumberFormatException` (such as `1999999999999999999L` - its reverse is too big), so it might just be better use a try block and catch the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: How about if i turn the return variable into a float or double? Would that work?

Comment: You should use BigInteger. You can input a String, catch conversion errors and do your algorithm using BigInteger. It has all the methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have another method reverse(char[]) that properly reverses the array of char, the exception you get is a NumberFormatException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8085774586302733229-"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
  at stackoverflowexamples.ReverseNumber.reverse(ReverseNumber.java:40)
  at stackoverflowexamples.ReverseNumber.display(ReverseNumber.java:21)
  at stackoverflowexamples.ReverseNumber.run(ReverseNumber.java:17)
  at stackoverflowexamples.StackOverflowExamples.main(StackOverflowExamples.java:19)
```

As khelwood pointed out above, you can see the problem is the - sign at the end of the string.

Responding to comment:

double or int will not solve the problem. As pbabcdefp pointed out, there are many more numbers that will crash the program. Any 19 digit number ending in 9 will crash it.

If you have to create a new long, then you will have to implement a lot of exception handling.